# Reloading/Refreshing Spring configuration file and refresh value only for selected variables

Tags: java, spring, configuration, app-config, spring-3

In spring app I'd like to have ability to change content of application.proporties and propagate these change to all bean values annotated by *@Value*.

I know that I can simply reload all Spring context but I don't want to do this. Some of components can't be recreated. I want to reload values only for seleted bean proporties.

I am using *Spring 3.2*

### My solution

I prototyped own solution but it requires use of reflection on some Spring internal classes. I'm looking for clearer solution

Get required internal Sping objects and make public methods/fields which I need:

```
    TypeConverter typeConverter = beanFactory.getTypeConverter();

    // get object which store autowiring metadata for beans
    Object annotationProcessor = beanFactory
            .getSingleton("org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor");

    // let it be public for my usage
    Method findMethod = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class ,"findAutowiringMetadata", Class.class);
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(findMethod);

    // let it be public for my usage
    Field checkedElements = ReflectionUtils.findField(InjectionMetadata.class, "checkedElements");
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(checkedElements);
```

Iterate over all beans and search for elements with my own annotation (@Reloadable). Then reload values for them

```
for (String name : allBeanNames) {

    Object bean = beanFactory.getSingleton(name);
    InjectionMetadata metadata = (InjectionMetadata) findMethod.invoke(
            annotationProcessor, bean.getClass());

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Set<InjectedElement> elements = (Set<InjectedElement>) checkedElements
            .get(metadata);

    for (InjectedElement element : elements) {
        Member member = element.getMember();
        // check for each elements if it has my own annotation which
        // means that it should be realoaded
        // check removed for simplify

        // get new value and load it
        String placeholder = valueAnnotation.value();
        String resolvedValue = env.resolvePlaceholders(placeholder);
        Object converted = typeConverter.convertIfNecessary(
                resolvedValue, type, field);

        // load value
        if (member instanceof Method) {
            ((Method) member).invoke(bean, converted);
        } else if (member instanceof Field) {
            ((Field) member).set(bean, converted);
        }

    }
}
```

### Other solutions

http://www.wuenschenswert.net/wunschdenken/archives/107 - works for older version of spring

Comment: I know this is pretty old'ish - but I've posted a working solution in an other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53787761/330070 - hope that helps